# Ubuntu only using half the storage

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed a 256GB SSD on my laptop to dual boot Ubuntu. The people I sent the laptop for upgrading offered to install Ubuntu on the new SSD. Once I got it back I realised Ubuntu was only using half of the available SSD storage. After a bit of digging with GParted, I found out that the boot partition is using up the other half of the storage. I’m new to Ubuntu so I’m unfamiliar if that’s how the boot partition is or if something can be done to reduce the shrink the boot partition and grow the root partition. Thanks in advance

Comment: If they messed up as badly as you say, how can you be sure they didn't mess up something else about the system? I would reinstall.